# Double tested Regex not working at runtime

Tags: c#, html, regex, visual-studio-2010

I'm struggling for over a day with what I'd though would be an easy thing.

I need to parse a page's HTML to find some structured data.

Here's the test string:

```
<option value="0794">0794 - SANTA MARIA</option>
<option value="0795">0795 - ALICE COUTINHO</option>
<option value="0800">0800 - T.LARANJEIRAS (CIRCULAR A E B) - VIA T. CARAPINA/J. CAMBURI</option>
<option value="0801">0801 - T. LARANJEIRAS / T. CARAPINA - VIA VALPARAISO / J. LIMOEIRO</option>
<option value="0802">0802 - DIVINOPOLIS / T.LARANJEIRAS VIA CENTRO DA SERRA</option>
```

And here's the Regex pattern:

```
^\s+<option value="\d+">(?<linha>\d+) - (?<nome>(.*?))</option>$
```

When debugging with Visual Studio 2010 it find no matches.

Full code:

```
var pattern = @"^\s+<option value=""\d+"">(?<linha>\d+) - (?<nome>(.*?))</option>$";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches = regex.Matches(html)
```

`html` is the test string and `matches.Count` is always `0`.

I've already tested on http://regexhero.net/tester/ and on http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx and it works perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't `<option value="(?<linha>\d+)">\1 - (?<nome>[^<]+)</option>` work for you?

Comment: No matches using `[^<]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems.  First, there's the `^\s+` at the beginning of the regex.  In Multiline mode, `^` matches the position following a linefeed.  `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters.  But there aren't any whitespace characters after the linefeeds.  If you think there *might* be space or tab characters at the beginning of the line, you should change the `+` to `*`; otherwise, just drop the `\s+`.

Second, the regex ends with `$`, which matches just *before* a linefeed.  But when I copied the text from your post, the lines ended with `\r\n` (carriage-return + linefeed), and you aren't accounting for the `\r`.

When I change the `^\s+` to `^` and the `$` to `\r?$`, I get five matches.  By the way, the second problem is .NET's fault, not yours; `$` in multiline mode *should* match before `\r`, as detailed [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Line_Boundaries).

Comment: The original string has four spaces on the beggining of the line. When I pasted it here it became the block identation syntax and I forgot to readd them back.  Anyway, the `\r?$` did the trick. I knew I was not (that) crazy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using the test string as it presented here it's clear that the problem is in the next part:

```
\s+
```

That means one or more symbols, and test string doesn't have whitespace characters before any of the lines. `\s*` does the trick.

Comment: That was a copy+paste issue. The existing four spaces became the block ident for StackOverflow and I forgot to add them again. :)

The original string has four spaces on the beggining of each line.